# Does Stack Overflow have a sitemap?

Tags: discussion, sitemap

I can't find the sitemap. Is there one? I know some websites use a gzip file to compress the sitemap but I can't seem to find that either. Is SO sitemapless?

I'm actually just looking for examples of what a "good" sitemap looks like and that's what provoked this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does, but we protect it because there was a LOT of abuse around it. Please do not ask.

If you do anything with the sitemap we don't like, your IP will be banned without hesitation.

Comment: I am in your sitemap, drawing ponies and eating waffles.

Comment: How exactly does a sitemap get abused? This could be interesting.

Comment: I wonder if people were using the sitemap to try and maintain live feeds of new questions and answers instead of screen scraping the main page.

Comment: I too am curious how a sitemap can be abused.

Comment: Jeff discussed the "site map" in a previous episode of the podcast. Apparently it's HUGE, includes thousands of questions, etc.

Comment: It's more or less a dump of SO, or a part of it. Therefore it causes high load and traffic. In the meantime, Jeff even mentioned deploying a second server just to make sure Google doesn't get throttled when indexing. Public availability could harm SO by causing too much resource usage.