# Where is the link to access the Hottest Questions/Answers page for a particular tag?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, hot-questions

I was searching for something about XQuery when I came across a link (see below) that shows the hottest answers for a particular tag, according to rank, day, week, etc.

[image: "Hottest 'xquery-sql Answers - Stack Overflow" in Google search results]

For the [xquery-sql](/questions/tagged/xquery-sql) tag, the URL is **https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xquery-sql/hot**

This was kinda cool, so I got interested and tried to find similar pages for other tags. I looked under "Tags" and "Questions", but I could not find any links to these pages. How does Stack Overflow manage access to such pages? Where are the options linking to such pages?

If the pages are available, shouldn't Stack Overflow make it easily accessible?

Comment: Because [they like to hide all the cool things from us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites). It's all part of the fun!

Comment: As an aside: I truly dislike these "hottest", "newest", "recently active", "unanswered" and "highest voted" results in Google. Those pages are often outdated as soon as you click them, so one needs Google cache to find the actual hit. I've always assumed it's needed to make other search results better, but still: very annoying, I feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to a tag page or hovering it, and then clicking through to [its top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xquery-sql/topusers), will get you a page that also has the "hot" and "new" tab. This page is titled "Tag Info" just like [a regular tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xquery-sql/info) page. Odd.

I'm not sure if that's how Google finds them; it might be using [the sitemap.xml](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33965/how-does-stack-overflow-protect-its-sitemap/33967#33967) instead.

Comment: Well, not *exactly* like it. One uses Title Case, the other doesn't. :-)

Comment: It should be accessible through a separate TAB under TAG menu. How can they keep such an important page not accesible through menu !! It should be more conspicuous.