# Can I see something similar to a reputation line graph but for the number of questions in a tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, statistics

I think this would be interesting to see what the growth rates are like for new languages (like [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala)). These graphs could be used as a demonstration that a particular language is gaining traction for example.

*EDIT: yes, I **know** that I could get this myself from the data dump but it seems like a useful stat to me and one that people would use. Hence the suggestion*

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with [Paul Tarjan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130173/paul-tarjan)'s [number tracking service](http://webnumbr.com/), if it wasn't [currently blocked by SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38582/why-is-my-crawler-banned-by-stackoverflow).

Answer (score -1):

You can always download the data dump and plot the graph yourself

Comment: Yeah - that's a great answer, which could be leveled at any feature request! I think it would be a useful stat and people would be interested in it