# Where is the sitemap.xml file for StackOverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, sitemap

Searching Google for:

`filetype:xml site:stackoverflow.com`

gives you as the first result:

`Stack Overflow sitemap`

But clicking on it stackoverflow.com shows you a "Page Not Found" page. [Here is the Google cached version of the file](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TN1KGcAqBQwJ:stackoverflow.com/sitemap.xml+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) (available in this case on the 3rd May).

Is StackOverflow redirecting me based on the User-Agent header (because I try to load it from a browser)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099393/sitemap-on-a-highly-dynamic-website#comment914228_1099421) says that SO is blocking browsers to see the file.

So in this case I would need to know how to spoof a search engine bot. For this I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608645/how-to-spoof-a-search-engine-bot-with-curl)

And I have also asked the question on [meta stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180656/how-to-access-the-sitemap-xml-file-of-stackoverflow-com)