# Should this edit be rolled back?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, rollbacks, specific-edit

I had got [this particular edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3484356) in the review queue. When I clicked on the *reject* button it showed that the edit was already approved. I honestly felt that even though the edit was related to the question description, it was a bit too of much a change(contextually).

Should I rollback this edit or does it seem alright? I wanted to know the thoughts of the community on this edit, before rolling it back. Because if there is a proper justification for such an edit, then I might withhold the rollback as well.

Comment: No, looks like valid edit. "rephrased title to better fit body" - from quick look it looks like that's what it is indeed. Personally I would have skipped it as I'm not familiar with those tags but I also won't roll back.

Comment: Yes. Old title is shorter and contains all the relevant information. The edited description is an example for "how not to use a title"

Comment: Aha! A yes and a no, first up. This sure makes things easier for me :( Can both of you try to give a bit more justification for your respective suggestions? I'd would to have some justifications before deciding myself on what to do regarding this edit(and may be, few more in the future).

Comment: It's not really important; such edits are in the "gray zone" where the same exact edit can one time be approved and other time be rejected. I'll explain why rollback is not justified in this case. Keep in mind that rollback is whole new edit, another revision and another bump. Unless the edit was really bad there's no point to roll it back. Maybe part of what @JohannesKuhn said is true and old title contained relevant information but I disagree the new title is "how not to use a title". Title should be informative in my opinion,  size doesn't always matter. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The edited title is ever so slightly more descriptive of the situation -- it explains *why* the question is being asked -- and moves the less-meaningful question words to the less-visible-in-search-results end of the title, making it perhaps more recognizable in those results as a match for the searcher's problem.

It's squarely in "meh" territory, to my mind. I'm not sure I would have approved it, but I think it can stand (or be left up to the question owner to roll back).

Comment: Agreed to the first part, but regarding the search results thing, it'd have got more hits had the question stayed in the previous form, as most users using Google would end up asking it a search query like this *How to get around maximum CUDA run time*(with or without the question mark).

Comment: "get around cuda max run time" should still turn up the question, @R.J. Google's smart enough for that.

Comment: Exactly my point. The previous title would have turned up for the search query you gave too. But would the newer title be in the top 10 hits? I really doubt that, as the question title has been changed substantially.

Comment: Google's cache of the question should be updated sometime in the next half-hour, so let's see what happens.

Comment: I don't know how it works from Google's end but the search query returns that question but with the old name and not the new one. Even now. Any idea on that?

Comment: Yeah, that's surprising. Generally it's [super fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98083/how-does-stackoverflow-get-indexed-by-google-in-such-as-fast-manner). Maybe it's because the question is so old?

Comment: Just a note, this question is still the top hit for me on "get around cuda max run time": http://i.stack.imgur.com/OKW2J.png

Comment: Yeah I noticed that myself a few times and that's why I left the edit as such and accepted your answer too. Guess the rollback wasn't really required, though I'm glad that I could get a few insights regarding such cases.