# How does StackOverflow ensure its questions get indexed by search engines?

Tags: discussion, seo

There's so many questions on SO and they quickly become hard to find unless you search for them. How does StackOverflow show all these pages to crawlers for SEO?

Comment: Using an insanely large sitemap.xml.

Comment: @SLaks where is it? `GET /sitemap.xml` 404s for me

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: [StackOverflow and Google search](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/stackoverflow-and-google-search)

Comment: @hdgarrood: [Does stackoverflow have a sitemap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19805)