# Stack Overflow Sitemap implementation when question is deleted or updated?

Tags: discussion, seo, sitemap

As Jeff Atwood answers in "[Does Stack Overflow have a sitemap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19805/does-stackoverflow-have-a-sitemap)", Stack Overflow has a Sitemap, but they protect it.

My question is about Stack Overflow Sitemap implementation when a question is "deleted" or "updated".

***When updated***
Does Stack Overflow generate a new record of this question URL in the current sitemap file then submit/ping again?

Or change the last modified date in the question URL record in the old sitemap file then submit/ping again?

***When deleted***
Does Stack Overflow delete the question URL record of this question from sitemap file?

Or how does it inform search engines about a deleted question to remove it from the index?